# Magento event not triggered when order cancel programmatically

Tags: magento

I am running a script to cancel order automatically.
My script looks something like this.

```
$order->cancel()->save();
```

The problem with this is that, it cancels order correctly but does not seem to dispatch `order_cancel_after` event.

How should I solve this, can I dispatch this event in my script? Why is this cancel action different from click the cancel button in the backend order page?

Comment: Can you share added event handle in your extension's config.xml

Comment: It is the enterprise reward extension, I want to trigger order_cancel_after so this extension will return rewards back to customer.

Comment: @Jack I'm actually dealing with the exact same problem in Magento 2 EE right now. It appears that the order_cancel_after event in Magento_Rewards is only configured to fire on the backend. I'll add an answer to show how to add module to register an event observer for this on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with to get the `order_cancel_after` event to fire on the frontend when `$order->cancel()` is called. I had to implement this for a Magento_Authorizenet issue where that event wasn't being fired when credit card's were declined.

**Edit**: I just realized your question was for Magento 1 EE. I'll leave this here in case anyone is having this issue on Magento 2 EE as well.

Create the following files with the specified content (Replacing **[Vendor]** with your vendor name):

## app/code/[Vendor]/Reward/registration.php

This file is responsible for letting Magento know about your module. After adding all files in this answer, you will need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor]_Reward',
    __DIR__
);
```

## app/code/[Vendor]/Reward/etc/module.xml

This file declares the setup version of the module and any modules it depends on (Magento_Reward in our case).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_Reward" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Reward"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

## app/code/[Vendor]/Reward/etc/frontend/events.xml

This file will register the stock Magento_Reward observer that is already defined for adminhtml (backend), but do it for the frontend (because of it's location in etc/**frontend**):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="order_cancel_after">
        <observer name="magento_reward" instance="Magento\Reward\Observer\ReturnRewardPoints" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch your own event like this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'order_cancel_after',
        array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote())
    );
```

Place this code accroding to your usage.